# Possible to include mxmlc flex compiler inside an AIR app?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

Im currently developing an swf 3D Player for the web with Flex SDK. My goal is to create an air application that lets the user load models and export them to .swf 3D player to make those 3d models viewable over the web. Im using FlashDevelop.

My original goal was to include the mxmlc compiler and the whole flex sdk inside my air apps bin directory and run those with airs native extensions with arguments(command line). The problem is that flex sdk is about 800Mb size and again required JRE to run mxmlc.

Is there a way to include a minimalistic compiler inside my air application which doesn't require 800mb+ ? I know I just could output a general swf that first loads a config file with paths to the model and textures and then loads those, but I want the models and textures to be included inside the swf to make those safe from being easily downloaded. Any suggestions?

Comment: So your air app would just load pre-made models and generate .SWF files from them? Why would your swf 3D player not just load the model files directly?

Comment: If I load the models inside the .swf 3d Player external(via URLRequest) this would mean that the original 3d models are exposed for download by other users as they have to be in the webspace somewhere. I want the 3d files to be included inside the .swf for increased safety. I heard file download can be restricted to applications but I really would like to make it as user friendly as possible. E.g. press 'export to swf button' and upload the result to your webspace, done.

Comment: @DenisDik I'm not sure where to start: Embedding the 3D Model inside a SWF doesn't offer it much more protection; as SWFs are easily reverse compiled; so I suspect you're adding a lot of work to your application development for very little gains in data protection.  You can serve up files through a URL without storing the files in a web accessible directory [ColdFusion does this with cfcontent]. The concept is load the files bytes from the file system and stream them to browser. Your code can perform security check to make sure access is authorized.

Comment: So anyone who gets the SWf file will  have your models. that is bad security. What you need to do is download the files as needed but check auth when you do

Comment: To address your original question; you can probably create a smaller version of the SDK by removing source code files and other binaries such as ASDocs and then trying to compile to see if it still works.

Comment: @Reboog711 he would probably have to wrap it up in a native extension

Comment: @The_asMan I think he could use NativeProcess for this without the complexity of a Native Extension

Comment: @ Reboog711 can you please provide more information on the streaming approach, it sounds promising. I didnt know that swfs can be easily decompiled. Edit: I was able to implement a stripped down flex sdk and standalone jre inside my air projects bin folder and it works in debug mode, once I publish and package nativeproccess.issupported is always false and i cant run mxmlc anymore.

Comment: @DenisDik I'm not sure what additional info you need.  The generic process is "Make sure user has access to get the file; then load the file from the server's file system; set a mime-type [if needed]; then stream the bytes back to the client.  CF makes this easy with cfcontent: http://www.cfquickdocs.com/?sourceid=cfQDSearch1.03&getDoc=cfcontent#cfcontent

Comment: @DenisDik On your `isSupported` problem: `"This property returns true only when running in the extendedDesktop profile. In addition, NativeProcess.isSupported is always false for applications installed as an AIR file. You must package an AIR application using the ADT -target native flag in order to use the NativeProcess class."` from the docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html

Comment: @DenisDik Even if you get it working though, I don't think this is the right way to solve your problem, especially considering that embedding your model in the swf makes it easier to download, if anything :)

Comment: I think the best approach would be to write a web service which does the compilation for your app.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the specific question asked, but it's too long for a comment.

Your problem is not how to include the flex compiler with AIR, it's how to stop the models and textures in the SWF from being downloaded easily.

First of all, there's no 100% secure answer; the SWF format is easily decompiled (so embedding 1 file per SWF is out), and if determined enough, someone can look at the memory of your application to find what they need; this is all about stopping the easy copy.

Off the top of my head, these are some of the ways you can do it, assuming that your end goal is an online 3D model viewer:

**1) Have your own format**

While technically not impossible, it is pretty awkward; basically you write your own format for storing and displaying models (essentially what most 3D modelling software does). This means that if someone gets hold of a model file, it's useless to them unless they write a parser (naturally, you'll need to protect your display SWF). If the purpose of your viewer is for other users to buy the model, then they'll need it in a format that they can use, so your workflow goes something like this:

*Create model in common format -> convert to custom format for display in your player -> user browses and hits "buy" -> they download the common format file*

**2) Load the 3D model from your site**

The simplest option; just load the model directly from your server, similar to how you'd load an image. To stop people from downloading the file directly, store them above the `htdocs` folder, and access them through a local URI in flash. So your server file system looks something like this:

- models

  - Model1
  - Model2
  - ...
- htdocs

  - index.html
  - 3DPlayer.swf // loads models using a "../models/Model1" path

Thus only your SWF can access the models (though technically, as it's a file download, it might be in the browser cache - you should test it). To actually put the models into the `models` directory, you'll either need FTP access to the server, or need to create a simple script (using PHP or the like) to upload them.

**3) Stream the assets to your SWF**

As already mentioned, you can use something like ColdFusion to stream the assets directly to your SWF on demand. I've no experience in ColdFusion though, so I can't really say how this would work, but it shouldn't be too hard

**4) DB connection**

Assuming your models are stored as text blobs in a DB (e.g. MySQL or MongoDB), you can either connect directly with the SWF or use PHP and AMFPHP to connect to the db and stream the model that way.

You'll need to implement some security to make sure that people can't spoof your server calls, but the actual code to connect and return the value isn't too hard. As an added bonus, you're not tied to the SWF format, and can implement JS displayers etc if needed.